# Where can I find translations of OSI-approved licenses?

Tags: licensing, spoken-languages

I'm looking for a site/page somewhere that has translations of common open-source licenses. In particular, I'm looking for translations for the [MIT license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).

Is there a site or resource somewhere that has these translations?

Comment: How accurate do you need them to be? Just I'm thinking of google translate.

Comment: @Kevin: It needs to be very accurate.

Comment: @George Edison:  You aren't likely to get 100% accurate translations of legal text from one language to another.  Moreover, anything licensed with a translation of a license isn't licensed with the original license, and if there's a requirement for an OSI-approved license you'll have to stick to English.  However, the MIT license isn't very long or complicated, so you should be able to write a similar license easily in any language you're familiar with.

Comment: @David: Unfortunately I am not really fluent in *any* language other than English. Someone else has translated a large portion of my application into another language and I wanted to spare them the hassle of translating the license. I just took it for granted that someone had already done this somewhere and I could just copy the translation.

Comment: What languages do you need?

Comment: @txwiki: Dutch primarily.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the wikipedia page of the MIT licence http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License, you can change to other language pages by wikipedia on the left sidebar.

- Example for Franch:
  http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licence_MIT
- Example for German:
  http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT-Lizenz
- Example for Dutch:
  http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT-licentie

The other language pages have translations for the original licence.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Do you know if reproducing the translations would fit Wikipedia's content licensing?

Comment: The licence from Wikipedia is [Creative Commons Attribution/Share Alike](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lizenzbestimmungen_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported). You need to check yourself if the restrictions work for you.